# android, last line of textview inside of scrollview slightly cutoff

Tags: android, scrollview, android-edittext

The last line of the textview gets slightly cutoff. Letters that are larger and below are cut off (g,j,y...). None of the solutions I have found or tried worked, like adding padding, margin, removing layout_gravity... 
That happens when changing text, and setting several lines, not with default string.

The code below is inside a FrameLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/window"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:background="@color/royal_blue" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:background="@color/royal_blue"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/selectLeft"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOptions"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:gravity="right" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/selectRight"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"



            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonOptions"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_shadow"                
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
    android:background="@color/darker_blue" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar_shadow"                
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/IntroduceWord"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/resize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Resize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:paddingRight="-8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="-0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/corner_blue" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/royal_blue" />
```

Comment: Can you post the whole XML layout code ?

Comment: Updated with the rest of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your `TextView` which is inside `ScrollView` , add `android:paddingBottom="10dip"`
It will work perfectly. You give any value for padding.

Comment: Thanks. I was sure I had tried this (with dp that I understand it's the same as dip), but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Try either  ScrollView android:paddingBottom="0dp"  or  TextView android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

Comment: None of them worked. The padding at the bottom of the scroll view was to keep the text away from the other views

Answer (score 0):

Try as well(what @sootie8 said): android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Didn't work, for any of them. And besides, I wanted it to wrap_content for the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is very little you can do to get this working by altering the layouts. As I have found that some methods work only in some cases. I think it depends on the entire layout hierarchy and is not a one-size-fits-all solution. I have also noticed that it happens especially when you have a different font that you want to set to the TextView.

A sure shot method that I have experimented and tested is that you can set the font attributes in code after the view is inflated. I am assuming that you have a font in the assets/fonts folder that you want to you.

For eg in a Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    tv.setText("Insert text that needs to be displayed");
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "Fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeFace , 0); // 0 is normal font
    tv.setPadding(10,  0, 10, 0); // This is not mandatory
}
```

And in an Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(Resource.Layout.main_activity);
    TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    tv.setText("Insert text that needs to be displayed");
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "Fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeFace , 0); // 0 is normal font
    tv.setPadding(10,  0, 10, 0); // This is not mandatory
}
```